# Error when running fresh nuxt 2 project with node 16

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, nuxt.js

I am on MacOS Ventura 13.1. I am using nvm `0.39.3` and I installed `nvm install 16.19.0`. I then create a fresh nuxt 2 project using this command `npx create-nuxt-app testing_node`. `node -v` is `16.19.0` and `npm -v` is `8.19.3`.

Out of the box package json file

```
{
  "name": "testing_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
```

When I run `npm run dev` I get this error right away without installing any other deps or making any configuration changes:

```
> testing_node@1.0.0 dev
> nuxt


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.16.1                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                10:35:26
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                   10:35:26
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                                                10:35:26
✔ Builder initialized                                                                              10:35:26
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                             10:35:26

 ERROR  Cannot find module 'node-libs-browser'                                                     10:35:26
Require stack:
- /Users/admin/testing_node/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin.js
- /Users/admin/testing_node/node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js
- /Users/admin/testing_node/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/admin/testing_node/node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js
- /Users/admin/testing_node/node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js
- /Users/admin/testing_node/index.js

  Require stack:
  - node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin.js
  - node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js
  - node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
  - node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js
  - node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js
  - index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin.js:8:25)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
```

Config options I chose when creating nuxt app:

```
create-nuxt-app v5.0.0
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in testing_node
? Project name: testing_node
? Programming language: JavaScript
? Package manager: Npm
? UI framework: None
? Template engine: HTML
? Nuxt.js modules: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
? Linting tools: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
? Testing framework: None
? Rendering mode: Universal (SSR / SSG)
? Deployment target: Server (Node.js hosting)
? Development tools: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
```

The install after initialization finishes successfully but I do see all of these npm WARN's during install:

```
? Version control system: None
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.
2
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN   babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.
2
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN   babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN     babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/cache-loader
npm WARN   cache-loader@"^4.1.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/cache-loader
npm WARN     cache-loader@"^4.1.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: css-loader@5.2.7
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0" from css-loader@5.2.7
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader
npm WARN   css-loader@"^5.2.7" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN   1 more (vue-loader)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.
2
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN   babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN     babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/cache-loader
npm WARN   cache-loader@"^4.1.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/cache-loader
npm WARN     cache-loader@"^4.1.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: css-loader@5.2.7
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0" from css-loader@5.2.7
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader
npm WARN   css-loader@"^5.2.7" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN   1 more (vue-loader)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN Found: peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.
2
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"*" from hard-source-webpack-plugin@0.13.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin
npm WARN     hard-source-webpack-plugin@"^0.13.1" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN   babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader
npm WARN     babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from @nuxt/webpack@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
...
```

And this goes on and on until it finally shows this:

```
  Successfully created project testing_node

  To get started:

    cd testing_node
    npm run dev

  To build & start for production:

    cd testing_node
    npm run build
    npm run start
```

From what I understand, nuxt 2 should work with node 16. I know I can downgrade to node 14 and make this work but my objective is to use node 16.

Also, I see that the error is a missing dependency but this should not be the case since it's a fresh install, this tells me that there is some sort of peer/sub dependency issue in one of the nuxt packages. I don't want to/not should I have to manually install missing sub dependencies into my root package.json just because a peer dep is missing them.

Why is this happening even with a fresh nuxt 2 project? Could this be machine specific?

Comment: nuxt doesn't make an `index.js` from what I've seen and webpack is missing from the dependencies, what were all the options you picked on the create-nuxt-app setup? may do it again with other options

Comment: Hey @LawrenceCherone thanks for your reply. I added the requested info to the description above.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone added the npm warn log (or part of it without exceeding max char in S.O.) that I see when the initial npm install runs.

Comment: odd, did some tests, not sure where the index.js is coming from in yours but in create-nuxt-app v4.0.0 it will add the webpack dep, in v5.0.0 it won't, put `"webpack": "^4.46.0"` into deps and try again

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried adding`"webpack": "^4.46.0"` to dependencies and then running `npm i` then `npm run dev` and same error as above.  I also tried adding `"webpack": "^4.46.0"` then deleting the `lock` file and `node_modules` then running `npm i` and still the same original error is thrown. I am not sure where `index.js` is coming from either. I only see and `index.js` in `.nuxt/index.js` and one other one in `.nuxt/components/index.js`. But no `index.js` in the root of the repo.

Comment: Your project doesn't run in the end? Because npm warning are a common (non blocking) thing.

Comment: @kissu it does not run and installing webpack directly fails and then if I somehow force install it, running the project fails with an error that other deps are missing. Then if I try to install any subsequent dependencies, installing ANY deps fails.